# Why would I want to have a unit test method return a value?

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, resharper

I am wondering because the ReSharper rule "NUnit Test methods should not return any value" is disabled by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TestCase` attribute allows a named property of `Result` to be the specified which declares the expected result. This is compared, by nunit, against the return value of the test method. Something like:

```cs
[TestCase(12,3, Result=4)]
[TestCase(12,2, Result=6)]
[TestCase(12,4, Result=3)]
public int DivideTest(int n, int d)
{
  return( n / d );
}
```

If the analysis was enabled by default, this method would be erroneously flagged.